# Split stream into two streams

Tags: scala, functional-programming, stream

**Define the "split" function that divides a stream into two streams. The first list should contain elements with odd indexes and the second with even indexes. Example: `split(Stream(5, 6, 3, 2, 1)) -> Stream(5, 3, 1) and Stream(6, 2)`**

My attempt:

```
 def split(originalElements: Stream[Any]): (Stream[Any], Stream[Any]) = {
  var oddList: Stream[Any] = Stream();
  var evenList: Stream[Any] = Stream();

  for (i <- 0 until originalElements.length) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      oddList = oddList :+ originalElements(i)
    } else {
      evenList = evenList :+ originalElements(i)
    }
  }

  (oddList, evenList)
}

  println(split(Stream(5, 6, 3, 2, 1)))
```

I get this output -> `(Stream(5, <not computed>),Stream(6, <not computed>))`

I'm somehow confused in stream functions, could someone help me to understand what is wrong in this code and why I don't get the right output? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this `scala.collection.immutable.Stream`? Because that class is deprecated in Scala 2.13 (in favor of `scala.collection.immutable.LazyList`).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use partitioning function or reimplement it with `filter` and `filterNot` functions by yourself. Stream isn't a list, you shouldn't use `length`. Stream might be infinite.

```scala
  val s = Stream(5, 6, 3, 2, 1)

  val (oddStream, evenStream) = {
    val (odd, even) = s.zipWithIndex.partition {
      case (_, i) => i % 2 == 0
    }
    (odd.map(_._1), even.map(_._1))
  }
```